# How to filter a pandas dataframe till it finds a value in NaN column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df:
number score
12      NaN
13      NaN
14      NaN
15      NaN
16      10
17      NaN
18      NaN
```

1. I want to filter this data frame from the start to the row where it finds a number in the score column.
   So, after filtering the data frame should look like this:

> ```
> new_df:
> number    score
> 12        NaN
> 13        NaN
> 14        NaN
> 15        NaN
> 16        10
> ```

2. I want to filter this data frame from the row where it finds a number in the score column to the end of the data frame.
   So, after filtering the data frame should look like this:

> ```
> new_df:
> number   score
> 16       10
> 17        NaN
> 18        NaN
> ```

How do I filter this data frame?
Kindly help

Comment: Do you always have a single number? What happens if there are more?

Comment: Thank you very much Mozway & Scott Boston. Both of your solutions worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reverse `cummax` and boolean slicing:

```
new_df = df[df['score'].notna()[::-1].cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   number  score
0      12    NaN
1      13    NaN
2      14    NaN
3      15    NaN
4      16   10.0
```

For the second one, a simple `cummax`:

```
new_df = df[df['score'].notna().cummax()]
```

Output:

```
   number  score
4      16   10.0
5      17    NaN
6      18    NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.Series.last_valid_index` and `pd.Series.first_valid_index` like this:

```
df.loc[df['score'].first_valid_index():]
```

Output:

```
   number  score
4      16   10.0
5      17    NaN
6      18    NaN
```

And,

```
df.loc[:df['score'].last_valid_index()]
```

Output:

```
   number  score
0      12    NaN
1      13    NaN
2      14    NaN
3      15    NaN
4      16   10.0
```

And, if you wanted to clip leading NaN and trailing Nan you can combined the two.

```
df.loc[df['score'].first_valid_index():df['score'].last_valid_index()]
```

Output:

```
   number  score
4      16   10.0
```